# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service

Tags: java, android, illegalstateexception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Extra call to initialize analytics trackers
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2801)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:155)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1400)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Extra call to initialize analytics trackers
at com.apps.skytek.notify.AnalyticsTrackers.initialize(AnalyticsTrackers.java:32)
at com.apps.skytek.notify.NotificationService.onCreate(NotificationService.java:51)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2791)
... 9 more
```

How can i fix this crash? I know it's caused by Google Analytics but I dont understand why I have followed the proper guide from google on how to implement it!

Class with Analytics

```
   public void onCreate() {

    super.onCreate();
    context = getApplicationContext();
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService("notification");
    mInstance = this;
    AnalyticsTrackers.getInstance().get(AnalyticsTrackers.Target.APP);
    AnalyticsTrackers.initialize(this);


}

public static synchronized NotificationService getInstance() {
    return mInstance;
}

public synchronized Tracker getGoogleAnalyticsTracker() {
    AnalyticsTrackers analyticsTrackers = AnalyticsTrackers.getInstance();
    return analyticsTrackers.get(AnalyticsTrackers.Target.APP);
}

/***
 * Tracking screen view
 *
 * @param screenName screen name to be displayed on GA dashboard
 */
public void trackScreenView(String screenName) {
    Tracker t = getGoogleAnalyticsTracker();

    // Set screen name.
    t.setScreenName(screenName);

    // Send a screen view.
    t.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());

    GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).dispatchLocalHits();
}

/***
 * Tracking exception
 *
 * @param e exception to be tracked
 */
public void trackException(Exception e) {
    if (e != null) {
        Tracker t = getGoogleAnalyticsTracker();

        t.send(new HitBuilders.ExceptionBuilder()
                        .setDescription(
                                new StandardExceptionParser(this, null)
                                        .getDescription(Thread.currentThread().getName(), e))
                        .setFatal(false)
                        .build()
        );
    }
}

/***
 * Tracking event
 *
 * @param category event category
 * @param action   action of the event
 * @param label    label
 */
public void trackEvent(String category, String action, String label) {
    Tracker t = getGoogleAnalyticsTracker();

    // Build and send an Event.
    t.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder().setCategory(category).setAction(action).setLabel(label).build());
}
```

So I initialize the tracker and the tracker properties are in a separate XML file but it's acting like I'm trying to initialize it two times or something and I'm not too sure as to why its happening! Thanks allot for the help!

Comment: You have removed the most important part of stack-trace... Always the last (bottom most) Caused by and it's stack trace is where you should be debugging.

Comment: I need more information about this...

Comment: The full stacktrace and the code that is causing it are necessary for debugging...

Comment: @Codebender  I updated the post!

Comment: @jghg02 I updated the post!

Comment: @doublesharp I updated the post

Comment: @SkylerMartin did you ever find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try moving `initialize` to app class, so it will be called once in app life cycle.

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        AnalyticsTrackers.initialize(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need initializer the tracker instance into `onCreate` method.

```
AnalyticsApplication application = (AnalyticsApplication) getApplication();
myTracker = application.getDefaultTracker();
```

And then override the `onResume` method to set tracker.

```
myTracker.setScreenName("ScreenName" + name);
myTracker.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());
```

Comment: So Im a little confused on how to implement this into my code. If you look at my code there is nothing called AnalyticsApplication so I tried replacing that with my Application but that didn't work so looking at my code how can I modify that to fit my code?

Comment: The `AnalyticsApplication` is the call to the instance of Analytics and initialize the object with this. And this code only executed in your `onCreate` method in your `Activity` where you initialize the object?

Comment: Okay so I put in the class that Google made me implement called AnalyticsTracker but if i do this then I get an error saying inconvertible types. Also do I need to set up an integer or string for myTracker in the top part of my code for this section? myTracker = application.getDefaultTracker();

Comment: Yes try to initialise on the `onCreate` method

Answer (score -1):

The initialize method checks if the variable `mInstance` is null, and if it isn't,  it throws an exception. Well, you break your program because you give `mInstance` a non-`null` value before initializing. Don't do that.

Look at your own code:

```
mInstance = this; //Don't do that
AnalyticsTrackers.getInstance().get(AnalyticsTrackers.Target.APP);
AnalyticsTrackers.initialize(this); //☠
```